# Evaluate $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_3(\mathbb R)$ and $A^2+4A+3I=0$, I'm not quite sure how to start  evaluate $\operatorname{tr}(A)$

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the trace actually determined by the given equation ?

Comment: No, the trace is not uniquely determined for $n=3$. It  could be a typo: It is a $2\times 2$-matrix.

Answer (score 5):

You know that $(A+3I)(A+I)=0$. Hence, the eigenvalues are a subset of $\{-1,-3\}$. Therefore, the possible values of $\operatorname{tr}A$ (taking into account that it is a $3\times3$ matrix) are $-3$, $-5$, $-7$, and $-9$.

Comment: @ Oh dear José Carlos Santos , it was very awesome, thanks

Comment: @user62498 I'm glad I could help. That's not consensual, though. One person downvoted my answer.

Comment: The answer does not deserve a downvote, in my opinion.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jose's answer, we can give explicit $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ satisfying $A^2+4A+3I=0$, with different traces, e.g., $A=-I$, or $A=-3I$, or
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/r & -4 \cr r & 0 & -4r \cr 1 & 1/r & -5\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 9/r & -12 \cr r & 0 & -4r \cr 1 & 3/r & -7\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @ dear Dietrich Burde, I couldn't able to know how did you find such a matrix would you mind explaining a little more

Comment: This is easy. Write $A$ with $9$ unknowns. This gives $9$ equations in these unknowns via $A^2+4A+3I=0$. If you specify the trace, one gets a linear equation, making everything easy to solve.